# Removing WordPress Navigation menu

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'd like to remove all nav menus registered with `register_nav_menu` or similar functions. Can someone help me with this? This is what I've tried.

```
public static function _modify_template(){
    global $_wp_registered_nav_menus;
    $_wp_registered_nav_menus = array();
}
add_action('wp', array(__CLASS__, '_modify_template'));
```

`wp_delete_nav_menu` doesn't work either, though I'm pretty sure at was meant for `wp_create_nav_menu`, not `register_nav_menu`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to really prevent any navigation from showing up I used this solution.

```
if( $no_nav ){
    // Avoid `wp_nav_menu` outputting data before any database calls are made.
    add_filter('pre_wp_nav_menu', '_disable_navigation_menu');

    // Avoid `wp_get_nav_menu_object`, which is deeper to the core, from returning any data.
    // The filter above should be used with this one as you don't want WordPress to create a default navigation menu.
    add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_object', '_disable_navigation_menu');
}

function _disable_navigation_menu($output)
{
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function unhook_menus(){
    $menus = get_registered_nav_menus();

    foreach($menus as $name=>$desc){
         unregister_nav_menu( $name );
    }

    $menus= get_registered_nav_menus();

    var_dump($menus);
    if(!$menus)
        echo 'empty';

    exit;

}

add_action('init', 'unhook_menus', 100); // if not working double check when menus are actually registered!!
```

This will remove registered menus which is what you asked, but this does not actually mean no menu will be shown, menus are a db item so it will look for something with items in it.... you can use filters to poke around depending on the code used to call

'wp_get_nav_menu_object' --> if requested menu is found/ theme location menu
'wp_get_nav_menus' --> if neither of the previous are found

e.g.

```
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menus', 'inspect', 10, 2);

function inspect($menus,$args){
  var_dump($menus); 
  var_dump($args);

   return $menus;
}
```

Comment: What you said is correct 1+, but I didn't notice that my theme used `wp_get_nav_menu_object` instead of `wp_nav_menu` so that's why it caused some problems. I should've used the hooks. Thank.